# Multiple Entity Reference creation using Services and Autocomplete Widget

Tags: entities, services, ajax

This is in reference to:
[Entity Reference create problem with REST server using Services](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42658/entity-reference-create-problem-with-rest-server-using-services)
and
[How to use Services to create new node with Entity Reference field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40284/how-to-use-services-to-create-new-node-with-entity-reference-field)

What if I want to create multiple entity references in a certain field with widget type Autocomplete (not Autocomplete with tagging)?

for example, this doesn't work and results in only the 1st reference being added, not the 2nd reference:

```
"field_nodes_list": {
    "und": [
        {
            "target_id": "Title (8756)"
        },
        {
            "target_id": "Description (12983)"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried using Autocomplete tags style by doing the below, which works, but only if the field is less than 1024 characters. I want to use the non-tag Autocomplete method above to do the same thing:

```
"field_nodes_list": {
    "und": "Title (8756), Description (12983)"
}
```